# Metro 2033 Extreme GPU Heat

Tags: pc, graphics-card, metro-2033

I'm running an NVIDIA GeForce 560, with a good case with plenty of ventilation (2 front intake, 1 top exhaust, 1 back exhaust). Metro 2033 runs my card up to 75-80+ degrees Celsius. Although lowering the in game settings doesn't change this, the game runs smoothly at higher settings, it just heats up the card significantly.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is it normal? Any solutions?

Comment: My GTX 680 runs at 59°C in idle and 80-90°C on load. It's been that way since the very first day. Is there any reason you believe your GPU shouldn't run as hot as it does now?

Comment: This seems like a normal temperature. What is making you concerned about it?

Comment: It idles at roughly 35°C, and no other game will ramp up the heat that high. I haven't noticed another game that makes me hear the GPU fan over the case fans. If it's normal that's okay, but I'm not too comfortable with it being so high.

Comment: You may have already found a solution in the past month, but my guess is that the culprit is PhysX. It imposes a ton of extra calculations that you don't really need, and the extra processing might cause more heat. But, that is only a guess.

Comment: Can physx be disabled in-game?

Comment: Yes. Go into game settings and there is a PhysX check box